# Concept of clock tick and clock cycles

Tags: c, clock

I have written a very small code to measure the time taken by my multiplication algorithm :

```
  clock_t begin, end;
  float time_spent;

begin = clock();
a = b*c;
end = clock();
time_spent = (float)(end - begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

I am working with mingw under Windows.

I am guessing that `end = clock()` will give me the clock ticks at that particular moment. Subtracting it from `begin` will give me clock ticks consumed by multiplication. When I divide with `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`, I will get the total amount of time.

My first question is: Is there a difference between clock ticks and clock cycle?

My algorithm here is so small that the difference `end-begin` is 0. Does this mean that my code execution time was less than 1 tick and that's why I am getting zero?

Comment: Where does the term "clock cycle" come from? The docs I have found at http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/CPU-Time.html do not use such term, only ticks.

Comment: @Suma clock cycle refers to the CPU speed. A 2 GHz processor has 2G (2 * 10^9) clock cycles per second. It is not related to clock ticks.

Comment: clock() doesn't have anything to do with CPU clock cycles.  If you use MinGW then use QueryPerformanceCounter() to get a very high resolution timer that's suitable for profiling code.  Timing a single multiplication is however beyond the reach of QPF, you can't get meaningful results for operations that normally take a single cpu cycle.  Nor is it useful.  You can only get an *estimate* by repeating the instruction many times.

Answer (score 7):

Answering the difference between clock tick and clock cycle from a systems perspective

Every processor is accompanied by a physical clock (usually quartz crystal clock), which oscillates at certain frequency (vibrations/sec). The processor keeps track of time by the help of interrupts generated from the physical clock, which interrupts the processor at every time period `T`. This interrupt is called a 'clock tick'. CPU counts the number of interrupts it has seen since the system has started, and returns that value when you call `clock()`. By taking a difference between two clock ticks values (obtained from clock()), you would get how many interrupts that were seen between those two time points.

Most of the modern operating systems program the `T` value to be 1 microsecond i.e. the physical clock interrupts at every 1 microsecond, this is the lowest clock granularity which is widely supported by most of the physical clocks. With 1 microsecond as `T`, the clock cycle can be calculated as 1000000 per second. So, with this information, you can calculate the time elapsed from the difference of two clock ticks values i.e. diff between two ticks * tick period

NOTE: clock cycle defined by the OS has to be <= vibrations/sec on the physical clock, otherwise there will be a loss of precision

Answer (score 5):

> My first question is: Is there a difference between clock ticks and clock cycle?

Yes. A clock tick could be 1 millisecond or microsecond while the clock cycle could be 0.3 nanoseconds. On POSIX systems `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` must be defined as `1000000` (1 million). Note that if the CPU measurement cannot be obtained with microsecond resolution then the smallest jump in the return value from `clock()` will be larger than one.

> My algorithm here is so small that the difference end-begin is 0. Does this mean that my code execution time was less than 1 tick and that's why I am getting zero?

Yes. To get a better reading I suggest that you loop enough iterations so that you measure over several seconds.

Answer (score 4):

four your first question: clock ticks refer to the main system clock. It is the smallest unit of time recognized by the device. clock cycle is the time taken for a full processor pulse to complete. this u can recognize by your cpu cpeed given in Hz. a 2GHz processor performs 2,000,000,000 clock cycles per second.

for your second question: probably yes.

Comment: Are you sure? The docs seem to indicate clock is always in microseconds (CLOCKS_PER_SEC = 1000000) - see e.g. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/clock.html

Comment: i think what he asked was what is the difference between clock cycle and clock tick. i think he wanted to know the difference betwenn what the clock() function returns (the number of clock ticks) and what (in general terms) clock cycle mean.

Answer (score -1):

A clock cycle is a clock tick.

A clock cycle is the speed of a computer processor, or CPU, and is determined by the amount of time between two pulses of an oscillator. Generally speaking, the higher number of pulses per second, the faster the computer processor will be able to process information.