# What is a "tick"?

Tags: c#, time, cpu

I know it's a unit of time equal to 100 nanoseconds and, as far as I know, it's the smallest unit of time you can get in C#.

However what, exactly, are "ticks"? Is 1 tick = 1 CPU tick? I'd guess not but then how does the system know when to add/increment a tick?

Bonus: if no one can look beyond "A tick is 100 nanoseconds, deal with it." then how does the system "get;" a tick?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concept of clock tick and clock cycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25743995/concept-of-clock-tick-and-clock-cycles)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does DateTime.Now.Ticks exactly work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554136/how-does-datetime-now-ticks-exactly-work)

Comment: That's like asking what a millisecond is. A tick is 100 nanoseconds, and is the unit used for the Tick property of DateTime. That's it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson fair point, but then a millisecond can be explained and there's plenty of information about it, unlike a tick, where you get redirected to anything but a definition.

Comment: The system knows the CPU frequency, which it can use to relate a periodic timer interrupt to a fixed time allotment. (All this is way below the level of managed code.) Modern systems with variable frequency CPUs and power saving schemes complicate this a bit, and these things should be considered separate from an actual time of day clock, where things like NTP are used to keep the "real" time accurate (as the CPU frequency, even when taken from a stable clock, is typically nowhere near stable enough for accurate time over months or years).

Comment: @MatthewWatson the duality of man, feat the awesome JeroenMostert.

Comment: It is an abstract term, represents the smallest unit of time that can be represented.  There is not just one tick value.  Yes, it is 100 nanoseconds for DateTime.  But typically 15.625 msec for DateTime.Now, 10 msec if you use a browser, 1 msec if you use a browser from a company that also sells a mobile OS.  And a system-dependent value for Stopwatch, represented by its Frequency value.  Since it depends so strongly on the specific type or api that you use, abstracting it to "tick" can be useful.

Comment: A unit of time can have arbitryry precision... if I define an array of 1000 bytes to contain the value of a point in time, measured in femtoseconds starting at January 2000, then I have a unit of time thats smaller than your *"smallest unit of time you can get in C#"*. `DateTime` is a data container first. Don't mix the data object with the oh so convenient methods (properties) to retrieve such an object with a fairly accurate representation of the current date and time.

Comment: @grek40 I wasn't, at all, even hinting at DateTime.

Comment: @HansPassant, so a "tick" is actually specific to whatever thing we are taking about? I thought it was tied to general CPU method of operation, thus making it a more general, perhaps system-wide, term. So in the end it's just an abstraction that's different for each object/thing?

Comment: @J.Doe ok sorry, I thought you talk about `DateTime.Ticks` (or `DateTimeOffset.Ticks` for all I care), since you were talking about *the system incrementing a tick*, rather than the programmer manually changing the tick value. So, if it's not about `DateTime`, please explain more specifically, what ticks are you talking about?

Comment: I believe the question can be better phrased as "How come we have a time unit as Tick?"